# Blazor component virtualization - preserve state

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a list of employees (around 500). In a component I want to display this list. I display the list as a table. Each individual row is defined in a component. The user can edit a data row inline on demand. For that purpose I insert an input field when the user wants to edit the data. The following exemplifies my current solution:

```
<!--Parent Component-->
<table>
  <thead>[...]</thead>
  <tbody>
    <Virtualize Items="employeeData">
      <TableRow rowModel="context" />
    </Virtualize>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<!--Child Component-->

@if(IsInEditMode)
{
  <tr>    
    <td><input @bind="@employee.name" /></td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><button @onclick="SaveData">Save</button>
  </tr>
}
else 
{
  <tr>    
    <td>@employee.name</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><button @onclick="EnableEditing">Edit</button>
  </tr>
}
```

I introduced virtualization as I noticed a big delay while typing in the input fields. Using virtualization the typing is working perfectly fine again.

**As a result I noticed the following issue though:**

When I scroll out of sight, the rows get reset - the inserted data gets lost and the editing mode is turned off. My guess is that is happening because the row gets rerendered and by default
editing is turned off.

**How do I keep the state of specific components while using the virtualization feature?**

Comment: Can I suggest a state wrapper wich includes the value for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that virtualisation had problems rendering the child components. Integrating the child component into the parent component resolved the problems.
I'll try to investigate further whether this was a problem with my component or a problem of blazor's virtualisation.